# Django m2m relationship only saving sometimes through django admin

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

Have been banging my head against a wall on this one for a while.  I have a model called Car, in this is has a models.ManyToManyField of colours.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=70, default='', unique=True)
    colours = models.ManyToManyField('Colours')
    ...

    def fetch_data(self):
        #some code which gets data from an api and adds it to some fields
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fetch_data()
        super(Car, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

For a while this has been working seamlessly.  A Car can be saved with numerous colours.

Recently, if I select a colour in django admin when adding a Car, I click save, the Car will be created.  However, clicking back into the car in django admin and you can see there are no Colours attached to it.  And looking at the database, the m2m values have not been added.

However, if I stay on that Car's edit screen for a while (5 mins) in django admin, re click on the colours, and press save, it will save the colours half of the time.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue with this?  I have tried adding save_related() and save_model() in CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) but to no avail.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Code within admin.py for the Car model looks like this currently:

```
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    list_display = ('name','published') 
    list_filter = ['published','colours']

    # This is needed to save the many to many on cars -> colours
    # def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    #     super(CarAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)

    # def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    #     Car.fetch_data()
    #     super(Car, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: Django *first* saves the `Car` and *then* will update the m2m relation, since it needs a `Car` object for this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - hey Willem and thanks.  Yes I understand that.  However, it does save the Car, but most of the time it does not update the m2m relation.  That is my issue

Comment: @riou: can you share the `ModelAdmin` you use for the `Car`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have changed it back to simply:

```
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('name','published')

    list_filter = ['published','colours']
```

Comment: Hello @rlou provide your code inside your question by making an [edit].

Comment: hey @AnkitTiwari - have made the edit, thanks!  The commented code in admin is code i have tried as individual functions